# I want to create the filter screen same as amazon and flipkart in native android with java or kotlin. How is it possible?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpjlE.jpg)

so How is it possible?

like one side I can use Recycler View and another side Frame Layout but my question is in Frame Layout How can I add dynamic Fragment and Fragment Transaction according to Recyclerview Item?

like one side I can use Recycler View and another side Frame Layout but my question is in Frame Layout How can I add dynamic Fragment and Fragment Transaction according to Recyclerview Item?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please check that Image link Which I have added

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by having distinguish IDs for your items and pass that ID to the fragment using bundle, then you can load data in your fragment using the id u retrieve from the bundle. Hope this helps

Comment: How can I add dynamic Fragment?

Comment: Pass ID to the fragment then fetch data using the id finally display it. Since the ID will be different for each item, It will fetch different data.